# Using GeoPandas intersections to fit a grid on a geometry

Tags: python, geopandas

I'm trying to write a function that creates a grid over a vector shapefile using GeoPandas:

```py
def grid(src_vector, out_vector, size):

    # read the vector data in mercator proj
    gdf = gpd.read_file(src_vector).to_crs('EPSG:3857')
    
    # extract bounds from gdf 
    min_lon, min_lat, max_lon, max_lat = gdf.total_bounds
    
    # compute the longitudes and latitudes top left corner coordinates
    longitudes = np.arange(min_lon, max_lon, size)
    latitudes = np.arange(min_lat, max_lat, size)
    
    # create the grid centroids
    points = []
    for coords in product(longitudes, latitudes):
        points.append(Point(coords[0], coords[1]))

    # create a buffer grid in lat-long
    grid = gpd.GeoDataFrame({'geometry':points}, crs='EPSG:3857') \
        .buffer(size, cap_style=3) \
        .intersection(gdf) \
        .to_crs('EPSG:4326')
    
    # filter empty geometries
    grid = grid[np.invert(grid.is_empty)]
    
    # export as shapefile
    grid.to_file(out_vector)
    
    return
```

In order to test it I created a fake shape:

```py
nb_cell = 6
grid_size = 30

gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame({'geometry': [sg.Point(0,0)]}, crs='EPSG:3857').buffer(nb_cell*grid_size, cap_style=3)
dst = tmp_dir.joinpath('shapes.shp')
gdf.to_file(dst)
```

but when I launch my function `grid(dst, 'output.shp', grid_size)` I get the following error :

> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/geopandas/base.py:39: UserWarning: The indices of the two GeoSeries are different.

Does someone see what I have done wrong?

### edit

The objective is to create grid over country geometries. These geometries can include islands so multiple polygons. The idea is to create a grid on the full extends of the initial gdf and then cut all the grid cells that goes outside the country boundaries.

Based on the [documentation](https://geopandas.org/set_operations.html), intersection seems to be the way to go

Comment: `.intersection` is a row-wise operation which aligns both GeoSeries. What are you trying to do with it? Maybe `gpd.clip`  or `gpd.overlay` would suit the needs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `clip` not `intersection`.

```py
def grid(src_vector, out_vector, size):

    # read the vector data in mercator proj
    gdf = gpd.read_file(src_vector).to_crs('EPSG:3857')
    
    # extract bounds from gdf 
    min_lon, min_lat, max_lon, max_lat = gdf.total_bounds
    
    # compute the longitudes and latitudes top left corner coordinates
    longitudes = np.arange(min_lon, max_lon, size)
    latitudes = np.arange(min_lat, max_lat, size)
    
    # create the grid centroids
    points = []
    for coords in product(longitudes, latitudes):
        points.append(Point(coords[0], coords[1]))

    # create a buffer grid in lat-long
    grid = gpd.GeoDataFrame({'geometry':points}, crs='EPSG:3857') \
        .buffer(size, cap_style=3)

    # clip to geometries
    grid = gpd.clip(grid, gdf).to_crs('EPSG:4326')
    
    # export as shapefile
    grid.to_file(out_vector)
    
    return
```